# Can a MYSQL trigger access the name of connection's user?

Tags: mysql, triggers, audit

I don't seem to find a way of accessing the name of the database user who is performing the insert, update or delete in MYSQL.

In PostgreSQL, along with the objects NEW and OLD, there's a "variable" you don't have to declare containing the name of the conecction's database user.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name write a proper answer so I can accept it.